# Handle Optional parameters using IS NULL with an IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

How would I do to receive null values ​​or not, in the IN clause?

As I did below, when I put the null value, the search returns empty, but if I put it different from null, it returns.

My idea is to search only by date if the value of the IN clause is null

```sql
SELECT E.RTCA_CD_QMNUM
      ,E.RTIT_NR_ITEM
      ,D.RTSI_NR_SUBITEM
      ,B.PLOP_DT_INICIO
      ,B.PLOP_DT_FECHAMENTO
      ,D.RTSI_DT_MAIS_CEDO
      ,A.SSRT_CD_STATUS_SUBITEM_RT
      ,D.RTSI_DT_MAIS_TARDE
      ,A.PORT_DT_INCLUSAO
      ,C.PLCO_DS_PLANEJ_CONFIG
      ,F.ROTA_NM_ROTA
      ,H.CLLO_NM_CLUSTER_LOG
      ,G.ATEM_DT_INICIO
      ,I.TIAM_DS_TIPO_ATEND_MAR 
  FROM SIGIOP.PLANEJAMENTO_OPERACIONAL_RT A
 INNER JOIN SIGIOP.PLANEJAMENTO_OPERACIONAL B ON B.PLOP_SQ_PLANEJ_OPER = A.PLOP_SQ_PLANEJ_OPER
 INNER JOIN SIGIOP.PLANEJAMENTO_CONFIG C ON C.PLCO_SQ_PLANEJ_CONFIG = B.PLCO_SQ_PLANEJ_CONFIG
 INNER JOIN SIGIOP.RT_SUBITEM D ON D.RTSI_CD_RTSUBITEM = A.RTSI_CD_RTSUBITEM
 INNER JOIN SIGIOP.RT_ITEM E ON E.RTIT_CD_RTITEM = D.RTIT_CD_RTITEM
 INNER JOIN SIGIOP.ROTA F ON F.ROTA_SQ_ROTA = A.ROTA_SQ_ROTA
 INNER JOIN SIGIOP.ATENDIMENTO_MAR G ON G.ATEM_SQ_ATEND_MAR = A.ATEM_SQ_ATEND_MAR
 INNER JOIN SIGIOP.CLUSTER_LOG H ON H.CLLO_SQ_CLUSTER_LOG = G.CLLO_SQ_CLUSTER_LOG
 INNER JOIN SIGIOP.TIPO_ATENDIMENTO_MAR I ON I.TIAM_SQ_TIPO_ATEND_MAR = G.TIAM_SQ_TIPO_ATEND_MAR
 WHERE B.PLOP_DT_FECHAMENTO >= TO_DATE(:DATAINICIAL, 'DDMMYYYY') AND B.PLOP_DT_FECHAMENTO < TO_DATE(:DATAFINAL, 'DDMMYYYY')
   AND E.RTCA_CD_QMNUM IN (:1) OR E.RTCA_CD_QMNUM IS NULL
   AND A.MORE_SQ_MOTIVO_REPLANEJ IS NULL
   AND B.PLOP_IN_STATUS = 2
 ORDER BY E.RTCA_CD_QMNUM, E.RTIT_NR_ITEM, D.RTSI_NR_SUBITEM, B.PLOP_DT_INICIO;
```

Comment: You need parentheses around `(E.RTCA_CD_QMNUM IN (:1) OR E.RTCA_CD_QMNUM IS NULL)` otherwise the logic will not work as you expect.

Comment: @TonyAndrews Yep, You'r right . If I want to do the same thing with the date, I tried to follow your example, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only have to change this

```
AND ( E.RTCA_CD_QMNUM IN (:1) OR :1 IS NULL OR E.RTCA_CD_QMNUM IS NULL )
```

And for the dates, guessing you want to apply the same logic

```
WHERE 
( B.PLOP_DT_FECHAMENTO >= TO_DATE(:DATAINICIAL, 'DDMMYYYY') 
  OR 
  :DATINICIAL IS NULL OR B.PLOP_DT_FECHAMENTO IS NULL
) AND 
( B.PLOP_DT_FECHAMENTO < TO_DATE(:DATAFINAL, 'DDMMYYYY') 
  OR 
  :DATFINAL IS NULL OR B.PLOP_DT_FECHAMENTO IS NULL
)
```

Comment: Thx, Works. If I want to do the same thing with the date, I tried to follow your example, but it didn't work.

Comment: @AllPower, if it works, please upvote or accept the answer. Let me edit the answer to cover the date fields, but that was not part of the original question

Comment: @AllPower, I updated the answer. the best way to say thanks is to upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: Yep I would accept as an answer, just take the opportunity to find out if you could help me with this one more lol. Thank you very much!

Comment: you are very welcome. I put the logic for the dates, I hope you are looking for the same logic.